# How to access array swift 3?

Tags: swift

i have following array of array in swift 3

```
[[SideMenu.medications(csMedicationID: -1, name: "test medication", startDate: "Sep 9, 2017", onGoing: true, endDate: "", type: 2, dose: "5", frequencyS: "Every 2 hours", archived: false), SideMenu.medications(csMedicationID: -1, name: "Medication 4", startDate: "Sep 9, 2017", onGoing: true, endDate: "", type: 2, dose: "5", frequencyS: "Every 2 hours", archived: false)]]
```

How can i access this type of object.

Comment: If you're that stuck you really need a Swift primer book or reference. The [official book](https://itunes.apple.com/us/book/the-swift-programming-language-swift-3-1/id881256329?mt=11) is free and worth reading before you try this sort of thig.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an object called `SideMenu.medications` and that that array is an array of that object: `[SideMenu.medications]`, so do this:

```
let array = [[SideMenu.medications(csMedicationID: -1, name: "test medication", startDate: "Sep 9, 2017", onGoing: true, endDate: "", type: 2, dose: "5", frequencyS: "Every 2 hours", archived: false), SideMenu.medications(csMedicationID: -1, name: "Medication 4", startDate: "Sep 9, 2017", onGoing: true, endDate: "", type: 2, dose: "5", frequencyS: "Every 2 hours", archived: false)]]

for object in array {
    for sidemenu in object {
        print(sidmenu.name)
        print(sidemenu.startDate)
        etc...
    }
}
```

Comment: got an error

value of type 'Array<any>' has no member name

Comment: @sanjayrathod, as Moritz pointed out it´s an array in an array, checkout the update of how to iterate through that kind of array.